# How to set textview inside the radio button?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

For Game Application I use radio button to select answers. But requirement is 'value (text) should be inside the radio button'. Is it possible?. Thanks in advance. Please help on this.

Comment: Did you do any research?

Comment: I can use Custom text view. But for radio button I cant set like this.. right? thanks@PurpleDroid

Comment: In future why don't we have this type of requirement in android designing part? thanks for reply @Marius

Comment: May be you can then try custom radio button with a oval shape background around text and radio button

Comment: @Ramesh If my answer is good for you, please accept it, otherwise, add a comment explaining why it's not.

Comment: I used custom text view. Its working fine. Warm thanks to @PurpleDroid

Comment: As of official documentation I used custom text view. thanks for your reply @Marius

Answer (score 1):

Radio buttons support XML `android:text` attribute.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">
<RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_pirates"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/pirates"
    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
<RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_ninjas"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/ninjas"
    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

As of [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html).

Comment: As of official documentation I used custom text view. thanks for your reply.. :) @marius